# How to format all Migradoc Table's Cells at once?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm creating a Table using Migradoc, and I want to set all cells shading color and cell borders.

At this point I'm only able to do it Cell by cell:

```
        var tableRow = table.AddRow();            
        table.Cells[0].Shading.Color = Colors.LightBlue;
        table.Cells[0].Format.LeftIndent = 1;
        table.Cells[0].Borders.Color = Colors.White;
        table.Cells[0].Borders.Width = 4;

        table.Cells[1].Shading.Color = Colors.LightBlue;
        table.Cells[1].Format.LeftIndent = 1;
        table.Cells[1].Borders.Color = Colors.White;
        table.Cells[1].Borders.Width = 4;
```

If it were inside a loop, it is not so painful, but all my rows are created one by one.

**How can I set these properties to ALL CELLS in the table?**

Comment: What do you mean by "but all my rows are created one by one"? How does that prevent you from using a loop?

Comment: @Sweeper I mean that each row is not created within a loop, so for each row, I have to set the cell format this way.  I wonder if there is a way to set the cell format once, for the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix up `Rows`, `Columns` and `Style` to achieve what you want:

```
        // Create a new style called Table based on style Normal
        Style style = document.Styles.AddStyle("Table", "Normal"); //this is optional, you can have your own style :) 
        style.Font.Name = "Verdana";
        style.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
        style.Font.Size = 9;

        Table table = new Table();
        table.Style = "Table";
        table.Rows.LeftIndent = -1; //to indent all the rows
        table.Columns.Width = 4; //width of all the columns
        table.Borders.Color = Colors.White; //color of all the border 
        table.Shading.Color = Colors.LightBlue; //all the cells table shading color
```

Comment: Thanks Hassan... I was overcomplicating myself :)